# Why does the p-value of the scipy.stats.ketest drop when the number of samples increases?

Tags: scipy, statistics, sample, p-value, poisson

Now days I am working on a time-series event, and want to show it is NOT randomly generated events. For this purpose, I am trying to use the kstest in scipy. By the way, I have a question about the cipy.stats.kstest for the poisson distribution as follows,

--- Code 1---

```py
from scipy.stats import poisson, kstest

noPts = 100 # <<<<<<<<<<<<---------------
lambdaPoisson = 10

my_data = poisson.rvs(size = noPts, mu = lambdaPoisson)

ks_statistic, p_value = kstest(my_data, 'poisson', args=(lambdaPoisson,0))
print(ks_statistic, p_value)

0.18677614630310613 0.0015821590670650476
```

--- code 2 ---

```py
from scipy.stats import poisson, kstest

noPts = 1000 #<<<<<<<<<<<--------------
lambdaPoisson = 10

my_data = poisson.rvs(size = noPts, mu = lambdaPoisson)

ks_statistic, p_value = kstest(my_data, 'poisson', args=(lambdaPoisson,0))
print(ks_statistic, p_value)

0.13477614630310608 2.6511802749311937e-16
```

I expected that the larger number of data points would result in a more precise statistical match between the two distributions (poisson.rvs vs. kstest(poisson). Yes, the ks_statistics is getting smaller. BUT the p-value becomes very small which rejects the null hypothesis, that is very strange because the two distributions are the same 'Poisson' with the same parameter. What am I doing wrong?

Can someone understand and explain to me the discrepancy here?

Answer (score 0):

The documentation for `kstest` says it is only valid for continuous distributions. Poissons are discrete.

Comment: Hello pjs, I missed what the documentation says. By the way, I cannot find a Kolmogorov-Smirnov test of a homogenous Poisson process in SciPy. Could you give me any comments, please?

Comment: My comment is to not use Kolmogorov-Smirnov. For a discrete distribution, you could do a chi-squared goodness of fit test.

Comment: Thank you for your kind and swift reply. I wonder why SciPy does not provide the KS-test (non-parametric vs. parametric) for the discrete event analysis? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Wikipedia points out that for discrete distributions the KS test thresholds depend on the specific distribution in the null hypothesis. Allow me to point out that this has veered off-topic for the site. Stackoverflow is for programming problems, not statistics.